# how to get the Maximum prob size for a given machine in HPC Graph(SSCA2)

Tags: graph, benchmarking, hpc

I am one HPC guy and using  SSCA2(C code) in my work recently.

In most of the papers, "Maximum problem size for a given machine" is mentioned many times, but I couldn't find the way to calculate this value.

In their paper is using Sun E4500, it can quickly get that the 21 may be max problem size (writing data to disk is ignored here) . Here is what I doubt.

And one more quesiton is about the Performance Metrix - TEPS .  In Linpack, it shows that the best performance is not greater than 80%'s  total memory, so what is the best performance for SSCA2 ?

Reference: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwyysn4woarp3am/Design%20and%20Implementation%20of%20the%20HPCS%20Graph%20Analysis%20Benchmark%20on%20Symmetric%20Multiprocessors.pdf

Comment: Your reference links to a page with a message that the download limit was exceeded :)

Comment: Sorry sir, I thouhgt it was exceeded only for me, here is my own link https://www.dropbox.com/s/vwyysn4woarp3am/Design%20and%20Implementation%20of%20the%20HPCS%20Graph%20Analysis%20Benchmark%20on%20Symmetric%20Multiprocessors.pdf